# Attempt to Dynamically Change CSS with Javascript Failed. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made a simple bulletin board system with a PHP-based server-side program that generates JSON responses.

For the client's side I chose to dynamically generate all HTML codes using jQuery.

```
<body>
<ol class="list" id="viewList"></ol>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $.getJSON("list.php", function (json) {
    var nPosts = json.length;
    for (i = 0; i < nPosts; i++) {
        $('<ol/>', {
            class: "viewPost",
            id: "post" + i
        }).appendTo("#viewList");
        $('<li/>', {
            class: "viewAuthor",
            id: "author" + i,
            text: json[i].authorName
        }).appendTo("#post" + i);
        $('<li/>', {
            class: "viewEmail",
            id: "email" + i,
            text: json[i].authorEmail
        }).appendTo("#post" + i);
    }
  });
  //Problem HERE:    
  var post0 = document.getElementById("post0");
  post0['style']['border-top-width'] = '0px';
});
```

What I'm doing HERE is, to erase the dashed line, just for the *first* list item (li).

Tried both jQuery way ( $("#post0")... ) and Javascript way (above)
but both didn't take effect.

```
.list {
    border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
.viewPost {
    border-style: none;
    border-top-style: dashed; border-top-width: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle.

Comment: When the time has come to generate much HTML through javascript/AJAX, it would be wise to use a library like knockout.js to do data-binding/templating much more easily.

Comment: I'm just curious of why $('post0').css(...) didn't take effect...

Comment: the property `class` its not supose to be like `"class"` ? curious

Comment: Where did you find the CSS property `border-type-width` ?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. border-top-width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the collection in memory, and just check if the index is 0, and add the appropriate styles in the loop, and append everything once it's built :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("list.php", function (json) {
        var elems = $([]);

        $.each(json, function (index, value) { // assuming it's an array
            var ol = $('<ol />', {
                'class' : 'viewPost',
                id      : 'post' + index
            }),
            li1 = $('<li />', {
                'class' : 'viewAuthor',
                id      : 'author' + index,
                text    : value.authorName
            }),
            li2 = $('<li />', {
                'class' : 'viewEmail',
                id      : 'email' + index,
                text    : value.authorEmail
            });

            if (index === 0) ol.css('border-top-width', '0px');

            elems = elems.add(ol.append(li1, li2))
        });

        elems.appendTo('#viewList');
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the only answer working fine for now but I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

problem is that when the document is loaded those element is not generated so the jquery dont have any record that these element exist.

So to solve this problem you have to use delegate methods in jquery like

```
$(document).on('click',"class_or_id_which_is_created_runtime", function(e){
    //your code here 
    });
```

or you can add the javascript function at the time of creation of these elements

```
$('<ol/>', {
        class: "viewPost",
        id: "post" + i onClick=blah();
    }).appendTo("#viewList");
```

Comment: please tick the answer if it helped you solving your problem ;)

Comment: Strange that typeof document.getElementById("post0")=="undefined" returns false. If the element were not generated, that typeof value would be undefined, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think it will return false, as consider case of JAVA as the object which doesnot exist and we try to operate some function call on it throws nullpointer exception 
similarly how can we do typof of element which doesnot exist..

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing it this way (with javascript), you may want to have a look at CSS pseudo class `:first-child` :

```
ol li {
/*CSS properties for all elements here*/
}

ol li:first-child {
/* Specific CSS properties for the first element here */
}
```

Note : see also `:last-child` and `nth-child()` that could be of use to you
Note 2 : be aware this is only supported from IE9...

Comment: Looks very productive. But what if I had two different lists and I want them to have two different styles? And that's because I named every element using id. I thought if I named them properly I could later have access to them, just like I wrote "post0." If I change the style of li, then it will take effect on both lists, right?